# Where should I copy a portable game file?

Tags: filesystems

I downloaded Minecraft.jar for my kids. It's on my storage partition which doesn't mount by default. Where should I copy it on my system partition so it can be executed by others? Is it /opt? I don't have user rights there, should the root be the owner?

It is Kubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Do your kids have an account of their own on your PC? If so, why not place a copy of the .jar file in their home directory and give them the necessary perms for them to access it? Or you can also create a directory in / and drop it in that new directory

Comment: No, just one user account on this PC. I know I can create a new directory eg Games in my home directory but I wanted to do it in a right UNIX/Linux way.

Answer (score 1):

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview

For me both options seems good but I'd be inclined to use /opt as it is intended for software only. In /home you can usually find mix of different types of files, not necessary programs.

And being consistent with using /opt for software not managed by package installer will make your future migration to other or newer distribution easier.